# ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel after os_command.exec is redirected to standard output

Tags: oracle, ora-03113

I am getting a weird error that I just can't figure out....

I am getting an ORA-03113 error when executing a script. I have made a dummy script that gives the essence of what is happening:

```
declare
command_line varchar2(100);
v_stdout clob;
v_return number;
begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_stdout, true, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
command_line := './test.shl';
v_return := os_command.exec(p_command => command_line, p_stdout => v_stdout);
end;
/
```

test.shl:

```
echo 'Yay' > thisworked.log
```

When I execute this, the log file is not create and here is what happens:

```
SQL> @morebroke
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 77264
Session ID: 50 Serial number: 8551
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  stdout is THE one and only tty attached to your process, unless you redirect it.

When you connect via sqlplus oracle creates a separate process that talks to your process.  The oracle separate process cannot know about your special tty.  Why? Because a process running sqlplus can be anywhere on the network.

This is the same reason why dbms_output does nothing in a stored procedure.
From /proc on Solaris:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 oracle   oinstall       0 Sep  3 07:38 0 -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx   1 oracle   oinstall       0 Sep  3 07:38 1 -> /dev/null
```

These are stdin 0 and stdout 1 for a sqlplus process on the oracle server.  Notice that they use /dev/null - the "bitbucket" or black hole.

So you are asking that remote process process to exec, which means it passes along /dev/null as the terminal device.  The process has no clue about your stdout tty.

Use the `utl_file` package instead.  Or write compiled code -> like Pro*C, and do direct SQL, return the resultset to a local variable, then write it to a file.